# How do routers route packets in the event a router goes down?

Tags: routing, router, ip-routing

On the network backbone I mean.

If a router goes down will the network reroute the packets around the router?

Comment: What have you done to try to answer this question yourself before asking it here? What about what you found do you need clarification on?

Comment: I've tried mass tracerouting an up block to identify key routers, but I don't have the ddos capabilites to test what happens if a router goes down. Ive read lightly about routing protocols as well.

Comment: suggesting ddos is the preferred method of 'testing when a router goes down' is absurd.  You've read lightly (at most) about all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, routers use protocols like RIP (slightly outdated) or OSPF and IS-IS (more modern) to determine the best current route to a specific network. "Best" obviously will include "is not down".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to standard routing protocols like [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol), [OSPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First), [IS-IS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IS-IS) etc (as PaterSiul) mentions, there is also router-specific failover protocols like [HSRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol) or [CARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol).

Using a failover protocol means that when a router fails, a different physical device assumes the failed devices address and keeps on routing.